# Address of template/inline function in different translation units

Tags: c++

I was thinking how to encode a type in C++ as a constexpr, 
and I figured out that one could (hopefully) use an address of 
a dummy template function. This leads me to four questions:

1) Is address of a template function the same in all translation units?

2) Is taking the address of a template function enough to instantiate the function?

3) Is address of an inline function the same in all translation units? (This one is just out of curiosity :)

The last question is related to my simple-minded implementation of a ``static version" of typeid
(or it's 0-th order approximation), which is shown below : gcc (unlike clang) fails to compile 
on the statement

```
constexpr bool ok3 = (int_id != uint_id);
```

where `int_id` and `unint_id` are `constexpr`  of the type

```
using static_typeinfo = void (*)(void) ;
```

What is the source of the problem?
Of course, my code below assumes that the answer to 1 and 2 is yes -- but even if it's not 
I don't see why gcc fails to compile (with both -std=c++11 and -std=c++17).

Here is the code

```
#include<iostream>

using static_typeinfo = void (*)(void) ;

template<typename T>
void static_typeid_helper()
{
}

template< typename T >
constexpr static_typeinfo static_typeid(const T&)
{
    return &static_typeid_helper<T>;
}

template< typename T >
constexpr static_typeinfo static_typeid()
{
    return &static_typeid_helper<T>;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr static_typeinfo int_id = static_typeid(13);   
    constexpr static_typeinfo uint_id = static_typeid(1U);
    constexpr static_typeinfo int_id2 = static_typeid<int>();
    constexpr static_typeinfo uint_id2 = static_typeid(3U);

    constexpr bool ok1 = (uint_id2 == uint_id);  // ok
    constexpr bool ok2 = (int_id == int_id2);    // ok  

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << ok1 << ok2;  

    // Why the following statement fails to complile in gcc 8.3.0 even though it 
    // it works in clang 8.0.0 ? Error Message:
    //  error: ‘(static_typeid_helper<int> == static_typeid_helper<unsigned int>)’ 
    //  is not a constant expression

    constexpr bool ok3 = (int_id != uint_id);  
    std::cout << ok3 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "This leads me to four questions" - Then you should probably *ask four individual specific questions*.

Comment: This is plainly a compiler bug; of course different functions (including function template specializations) have different addresses.